# Challenge: How do I get variables from Salesforce to a workbook and back with results

Tags: data-export, import, excel

First off, I don't even like the direction my question is taking, but this is what is requested.  We are trying to create a form in SF for sales reps to use to input numbers, hit a button and receive results of those variables to form a new quote (a super calculator at its base level).  The inputs are to go to an Excel workbook which will take the numbers into formulas, calculate, and then send them back to Salesforce to the same screen.  I was looking at excel-connector and it seems to at least take care of the upload from the workbook, but what about the download? How can I contain the entire process?

Comment: Are the equations so complex that Excel is necessary? Or is the data being exported for non-SF users to review/manipulate?

Comment: It may not be that the equations are so complex, as it is that the data for comparison is proprietary/confidential.  The workbook is an initial workup of the data for pricing and we're trying to give sales staff the flexibility of changing some variables to fit the need without having them hound the staff.

Answer (score 5):

## Outside of the platform

Regardless of the path - All your users will have to be API enabled if they're to use external tools to communicate with SF. That means they could install Data Loader, start exporting data like crazy, some nasty guy can run a mass delete on his last day of work ;) I'm just saying that you might want to review your security settings if you'll go that route.

**Excel connector**

If you'll keep the column of generated Ids in excel connector you can highlight the Id cell (or whole row) and go "query selected rows".

Simple queries: http://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/wiki/Query. If you need more - functions like [`soql_table`](http://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/wiki/Advanced) might be interesting.

Excel connector can be a PITA with bigger sheets. First time you see these functions you go *OMG, a real time VLOOKUP to SF!*. Then as you start adding & moving rows/cols you realize that it likes to refetch the values fresh, freezing your work for couple seconds or minutes and that you'd be better off making the VLOOKUP's manually (with helper sheet of prefetched data).

It's bit of a tool aimed at power users and can easily explode. Specifying of endpoints, works best with field API names, users might need to know their password+security token... It has its uses but I wouldn't recommend for end users.

**Google spreadsheets**

There was some gossip about making it really easy to connect Google spreasheets and Force.com platform... but safe harbour, blah blah blah and Heroku guys were supposed to benefit from it most :/ There are some articles about it but they're horribly old (https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/salesforce - 2007, talks about S-Controls, may they rest in peace...). Still, if you don't mind some JS fighting and your company already uses Google Docs - it's worth trying out.

**Any other thing that will produce grids / formulas**

can be linked to SF through SOAP or REST API. You could hide the credentials of "Mr. Integration user" somewhere in the code so theoretically reps wouldn't need SF accounts to use some of the functionality.

If you have old app that performs these calculations - there are some libraries (most paid I think) that let you treat SF as a generic ODBC connection. Saw some cool stuff done with DBAmp for example (but there are tons of vendors, partners and tools to select from). Just a thought, depends on whether you're starting from scratch or you already have some code.

## On the platform

Visualforce, of course (well, or just native pages if you'd prefer to keep the logic in formula fields or triggers). Maybe sprinkled with some JS sugar (tons of JQuery table-like plugins), maybe with a REST service that for given input params would be returning calculation results (such service could be later reused in say mobile app).

**Export to Excel** out of the box is somewhat tricky. To Word - you'd use [Mail Merge](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mailmerge.htm&language=en_US). You can upvote [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqyRAAS) or just read the comments for some inspiration. Conga app could also be a way to go (basically you'd provide an Excel templaye that would be populated with data).

Alternatively this thing looks like pure magic (for xslx documents), haven't played with it yet though: http://neerajgupta999.blogspot.in/2012/06/multisheet-excel-from-apex.html

If it has to work for people who don't have SF licenses - you could expose the VF page as **Site**...